# Pass in a parameter list to create an object of the appropriate class

Tags: python

Please help! I am unable to pass a list of parameters to create the appropriate class. The read_package () function accepts the training code and a list of its parameters as input. The body of the function should contain a dictionary that maps the workout codes and the classes that need to be called for each workout type. The function must determine the type of training and create an object of the corresponding class, passing the parameters received in the second argument to it. The function should return this object.

```
packages = [
        ('SWM', [720, 1, 80, 25, 40]),
        ('RUN', [15000, 1, 75]),
        ('WLK', [9000, 1, 75, 180]),
    ]


def read_package(workout_type: str, data: list):

    dict = {
                'SWM': Swimming(data),
                'RUN': Running(data),
                'WLK': Walking(data)
            }

    for x, y in dict.items():
        if x == workout_type:
            return print(y)
        else:
            None


for workout_type, data in packages:
    training = read_package(workout_type, data)
```

If I understand correctly, then all three list with parameters are transferred in turn to each class. How can you fix that each list is passed to the correct class?

```
File "c:\Dev\task.py", line 133, in read_package
    'SWM': Swimming(),
TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments
```

Comment: I need function read_package to create an object of the corresponding class with the specified parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `dict` is trying to create an instance of each class type with the same parameters. Since each class takes different arguments this fails. Instead, make your lookup dictionary (`dict` is a bad name) contain the *class* instead of an *instance of a class*. Then you can instantiate the correct class by expanding `data` using the `*` operator.

```py
def read_package(workout_type: str, data: list):

    WORKOUT_CLASS_MAP = {
                'SWM': Swimming,
                'RUN': Running,
                'WLK': Walking
            }
    return WORKOUT_CLASS_MAP[workout_type](*data)
```

Also, `return print(...)` is nonsensical. I assumed you want to return the actual object you created.

Comment: Hi @Woodford, Maybe I didn't understand the idea of the solution, but I still have an error that arguments are not passed in the required number.
'SWM': Swimming(), TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments

Comment: You need to omit the `()` in your lookup table. You want the table to give you the *class* that you care about. You'll then use that class later to create an object of that class.

Comment: I am new to python. If the values in the dictionary only call the training type classes, then how do you create the objects of those classes?

Comment: It's just that after creating these objects, I have to transfer them to a new class and I get an error: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'duration', 'speed', 'distance', and 'calories'